# Basic combinatorics problem on arrangements with a story to it.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

First, lets give a short story about the problem which will follow:

I was at school here in Greece. We have school 5 days of the week. 2 random days we have 7 hours of lessons and the rest 6 hours of lessons. I wanted to return home, when possible, with one of my friends. However, we are not in the same class, so he has a different schedule. By taking all cases, I noticed that there will be at least 1 day of the week in which we will have the same hours of lessons, so we can return together.

I then thought of a more general statement:

If we arrange $n$ in number $A$ letters and $n - 1$ in number $B$ letters with $2$ ways, then there exists at least one same letter in the same place, if we assume that the first term for every arrangement has place 1.

I though about it myself and could not figure out a rigorous proof. Lastly, I posted it on a discord server dedicated to Olympiad Math and got this response:

"well... after we're done with the first way to arrange it a second way we could essentially swap the B's with (n-1) A's, thus leaving 1 A at the same place
so I would guess this is true."

Although I understand what is being said, I do not understand how this is enough to prove the original statement. So, if you happen to have a rigorous proof or some clever ideas, please share!

Comment: It feels like an application of the pigeonhole principle. Going back to the original problem, you have five slots/days and six classes/schedules to fit so it's bound that one of the days will have more than one class/schedule.

Comment: Perhaps simpler – between you, you have six 6-hour days, but there are only five days in the week, so two of those 6-hour days must be the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your original example, between you there are four $7$-hour days, so they can occur at most on four different days of the $5$-day week, so at least $5-4=1$ day must have both of you having $6$-hour days.

In your generalised form in the two arrangements of $2n-1$ letters ($n$ copies of A and $n-1$ of B) you can say the same thing: between the two arrangements, the Bs can appear in at most $2(n-1)$ different positions, so at least $(2n-1)-2(n-1)=1$ position must have As in both arrangements.

A pigeonhole argument would say there are $2n$ As across the two arrangements to put in $2n-1$ positions so at least one position has 2 As. This is essentially the same argument.